# My sorting algorithm in python freezes sometimes during runtime, can someone take a look?

Tags: python, algorithm, python-3.x, sorting

Basically what I've been trying to is, I'm picking out the  smallest and largest from the unsorted list, then appending them to a new list, then popping the smallest and largest from the old unsorted list and doing the process over and over until I end up with a sorted list. Please take a look at my code .

```
import random
import time

stack = [] #sorted list
numbersarray = [] #unsorted list

usersize = int(input("How many digits do you want in your array? ")) #numberofinputs
limit = 0
counter = 0


while limit <= usersize:
    numbersarray.append(random.randint(0,20)) #randomly input numbers into array
    limit = limit + 1

print(numbersarray) #prints the current unsorted array
start_time = time.time() #starts clock

subtractor = 0 #used later in code for changing index
while len(numbersarray) != 0:
    i = 0
    largest = numbersarray[i]
    size = len(numbersarray) -1
    smallest = numbersarray[i]

while (i < len(numbersarray)): 
    if numbersarray[i] >= largest:
        largest = numbersarray[i]
        index = i
    elif numbersarray[i] <= smallest:
        smallest = numbersarray[i]
        indextwo = i
    i = i+1

if (len(numbersarray) == 1): #this checks if there's only 1 number left.
    entry = int(stacksize/2 + 1)
    stack.insert(entry,numbersarray[0])
    break
else:
    if indextwo > index:
        numbersarray.pop(indextwo)
        numbersarray.pop(index)
    elif index > indextwo:
        numbersarray.pop(index)
        numbersarray.pop(indextwo)

stacksize = len(stack)
if stacksize == 0:
    stack.append(smallest)
    stack.append(largest)
elif stacksize != 0:
    stack.insert(stacksize-subtractor,largest) #the subtractor is dynamically changing the index of insertion.
    stack.insert(0+subtractor,smallest)
subtractor = subtractor + 1

print(stack)
print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a doubly nested while loop in which you scan the whole array for `max` and `min`s and then proceed to `.pop` elements from the list in *arbitrary positions*.

Considering that `pop` is of `O(N)` complexity for items not in the end of the list; your approach is highly inefficient and will pass out/freeze for large values of `usersize`. That's why, I'm guessing, the "sometimes" in your title happens when `usersize` is large.

In short, this is a case where you need to find a better algorithm to solve your problem.

Comment: I see what's happening, okay, I'll definitely look into it. I'm a beginner coder so, I'm just teaching myself sorting algorithms, which is why this is so bad, thankyou!